# Finding text inside a webpage with Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find a phone number on a web page in Selenium using Python. If the phone number has href tag, my code is working fine but if the tag is missing (mean phone no. is not clickable), it's not working.

**Steps:**

1. Check all website pages
2. Find phone number
3. Check phone no. is clickable or not.
4. If not, then make it clickable.

Can anyone help me out with this?

**CODE:**

```
    URL = driver.get("url.com")
    
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='(123) 111-1234']")
        if element.is_displayed():
            print("Phone number found")
    
                
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Phone number not found")
```

**Text:**

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, (123) 111-1234 when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into (123) 111-1234 electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including (123) 111-1234 versions of Lorem Ipsum

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code or URL if possible

Comment: How are you going to make a phone number clickable?

Comment: @vitaliis by adding tel in its href. I Will do that later on but for now, I am struggling with this issue. How I can search for phone no. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @Sonali I was testing on this site > https://leelawoffice.com/test-page-webinar/ Can you help me out with this ?